# How to clone a detached HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse provided by the Servlet Container?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to implement the following logic:
when I receive HttpServletRequeset and HttpServletResponse in main servlet's doService method (in the main web Container thread),I start A,B,C three threads (thread managed by my own program) to process other servlet in parallel mode,and then join each response from these servlet in main thread,and if one of my own thread (assume A thread) work slow,the main thread will finish,so main response will return to user.and the **A thread must continue work properly**,I will request the response of the A thread using AJAX in browser side later.

So,I want to clone the HttpServlettRequest and HttpServletResponse provided by the Servlet Container,and the cloned request and response must be detached(**When container's HttpServletTrequest and HttpServletResponse finished,the cloned request and reponse still work properly**).

The behave of the cloned request and response must be same as the Container's from my code's view.It can be followed and included.

Any idea?

Thanks very much!

L.J.W

Comment: You can't. Period. What's the functional requirement? Then we can provide better suited answers/suggestions to achieve the functional requirement.

Answer (score 7):

Cloning HTTP request and response is possible via HttpServletResponseWrapper class http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html. You can find an example of usage on Sun documentation https://web.archive.org/web/20120626033905/http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets8.html.

Notice this was a workaround from (at that time) Sun to address this problem as it was never planned that you could modify request and response information before committed.

You can use the wrapper to make a copy of Http information and the pass it to a different thread.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to create classes to act as a delegate to the HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects and then pass a reference to on to a Runnable object to process.

There are certain operations that can only be done once to an HttpRequest object ( reading from the inputstream springs to mind ), the delegate class would have to cater for this.

Not sure what you're going to do if the A, B and C threads make conflicting changes to the HttpResponse object though.

I think I'd prefer to not pass the HttpResponse object through to the processing threads and leave the logic for populating the response in the controlling servlet class

Comment: I want the cloned Request and response can be detached,so I can not pass the reference(etc,I can not use wrap method)

Comment: @LJW: what you say doesn't make sense at all. "I can not pass the reference" then you must not be using Java...

Comment: @L.J.W You can want but you won't _get_ as using the response when a response has been sent is undefined behaviour. In other words, it'll crash because the streams have (probably) been closed).

Comment: I can implement Response to override getWriter and getOutputstream to avoid stream closed issue.But how to process include and forward?these method is container-implemetion ..If I implemet my own Request,I am afraid the container can not process properly.

Comment: Create a class that implements Response, pass the acutal ( Server supplied ) response to its constructor and store that in a member variable. Delegate all the methods on your class to call the corresponding methods on the member variable, just overriding the ones that you need to change the functionality of. Would that help?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking to much of the HttpServletRequest. Once a request has been completed you shouldn't count on the request object being of any use. I don't recommend threading inside a J2EE container in most cases anyway but that's a different issue.

If you *must* handle the request in parallel I recommend you extract the data you need from the request object and send that to your threads and make the worker threads mostly Servlet ignorant with the exception of the HttpSession where they could store their computed values for the Ajax retrieval.

Comment: The thread must process servletrequet and response,I can not send other data type..

Comment: @L.J.W In other words, you'd need to implement a custom HttpRequest and HttpResponse and initialize it with data copied from  the given request and response. Don't copy the streams as that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The request and response classes aren't designed to be cloned or accessed from multiple threads. If you try to do so, you're bound to run into problems. I suggest that you re-think your requirements.