# Multiple sendRedirect

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a situation where in return of a request to a server, their needs to be multiple sendredirect, is it possible through

```
response.sendRedirect()
or 
request.forward()
```

Comment: What do you think sending multiple redirects means? What does sending a redirect do in the underlying http protocol?

Comment: what I want to do is notify several other servers about this request came,do the above approach support that or I have to open multiple HttpClient object as the request doesn't comes through browser, but ist a back channel

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do **is not possible** beacuse once a request is forwarded or redirected then the rest of the forwards which (multiple forwards) you are imply are not possible

If you must handle the request in parallel I recommend you extract the data you need from the request object and send that to your threads and make the worker threads mostly Servlet ignorant with the exception of the HttpSession where they could store their computed values for the Ajax retrieval.

### THis might help you

Cloning HTTP request and response is possible via HttpServletResponseWrapper class [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html.)You can find an example of usage on  [Sun documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets8.html.)

Notice this was a workaround from (at that time) Sun to address this problem as it was never planned that you could modify request and response information before committed.

You can use the wrapper to make a copy of Http information and the pass it to a different thread.

**Reference**
[StackOverlow cloning request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273579/how-to-clone-a-detached-httpservletrequest-and-httpservletresponse-provided-by-t)